# How to skip or ignore a row with an iF statement in ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there a way in ampscript to say IF this occurs, skip (or ignore) the row?

Essentially, I want to use an IF/ELSE to say "only show this sale if it's not in table x" or "skip this row when the sale is also in table x"?

The ampscript I'm using is below.

```
%%[
set @ProductRows = LookupRows("TABLE_1", "Email", "Yes")
if @ProductID = LookupRows("TABLE_2", "ProductID", @ProductID) then
[skip row command]
endif
]%%
```

Comment: You may be misunderstanding what results from lookuprows() function.  It's a row-set that you'll need to iterate through and then extract values with the row() and field() functions.  I have some examples here: http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/

Comment: Once you have a result-set it's a piece of cake to add a conditional to skip a particular row.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it by just leaving it blank, like so:

```
%%[ 
SET @ProductRows = LookupRows("TABLE_1", "Email", "Yes") 
IF @ProductID = LookupRows("TABLE_2", "ProductID", @ProductID)  THEN
/* do nothing */ 
ELSE
 /* Row Command */
ENDIF
]%%
```

Hope this helps!